# Вывод изображения с json в тест, в качестве дополнения к вопросу

Tags: javascript, html, json, изображения

Проблема заключается в выводе изображения в дополнение к текстовому вопросу - "undefined". Нужно, чтобы на каждый вопрос выводилось свое изображение с json. Помогите, пожалуйста.
В результате должно получиться что-то такое (это просто картинки :с):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="container">
      <div id="loader"></div>
      <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column hidden">
        <div  id="hud">
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
              Вопросы
            </p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p class="hud-prefix">
              Очки
            </p>
            <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
              0
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div >
        <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this questions</h2>
        <div id="qImg"></div> <!-- Тут проблема -->
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">А</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">Б</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">В</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">Г</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
```

```json
[
  {
    "question": "В каких случаях водители привлекаются к уголовной ответственности за нарушения Правил, повлекшие тяжкие последствия?",
    "choice1": "Только при причинении смерти человеку",
    "choice2": "При причинении смерти человеку или тяжкого вреда здоровью человека",
    "choice3": "При наличии пострадавшего (вне зависимости от степени тяжести полученных им повреждений) или причинении крупного материального ущерба",
    "choice4": "Только варианты 2 и 3",
    "answer": 2,
    "imgSrc": "image/1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "question": "Какое расстояние проедет транспортное средство за время, равное среднему времени реакции водителя, при скорости движения около 90 км/час?",
    "choice1": "Примерно 15 м",
    "choice2": "Примерно 25 м",
    "choice3": "Примерно 35 м",
    "choice4": "Примерно 45 м",
    "answer": 2,
    "imgSrc": "image/2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "question": "Какой неподвижный объект, не позволяющий продолжить движение по полосе, не относится к понятию «Препятствие»?",
    "choice1": "Дефект проезжей части",
    "choice2": "Посторонний предмет",
    "choice3": "Неисправное или поврежденное транспортное средство",
    "choice4": "Транспортное средство, остановившееся на этой полосе из-за образования затора",
    "answer": 4,
    "imgSrc": "image/3.png"
  }
]
```

```js
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));
const progressText = document.getElementById('progressText');
const scoreText = document.getElementById('score');
const progressBarFull = document.getElementById('progressBarFull');
const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
const qImg = document.getElementById("qImg");
let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = true;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuestions = [];

let questions = [];

fetch("questions.json")
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(loadedQuestions => {
    console.log(loadedQuestions);
    questions = loadedQuestions;
    startGame();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

qImg.innerHTML = "<img src="+ question.imgSrc +">"; // Тут проблема

//CONSTANTS
const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 3;



startGame = () => {
  questionCounter = 0;
  score = 0;
  availableQuestions = [...questions];
  getNewQuestion();
  game.classList.remove('hidden');
  loader.classList.add('hidden');
};
```

Comment: вы типа mustache возьмите и не парьтесь этим json ...с ним очень легко выводить - обычный html пишется

Comment: Попробуйте `qImg.src= question.imgSrc;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, немного перепутал, теперь все работает. Вот ответ, если не вникать в другие подробности (qImg был заменен, если что). Но спасибо за комментарии)

```js
image.innerHTML = "<img src='" + currentQuestion.image + "'>";
```